# Can someone better explain selectionDirection?

Tags: html, forms, input, attributes

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) "selectionDirection - The direction in which selection occurred. This is "forward" if the selection was made from left-to-right in an LTR locale or right-to-left in an RTL locale, or "backward" if the selection was made in the opposite direction. This can be "none" if the selection direction is unknown."

Per the tutorial I'm reading this is a form attribute that I should know about, yet I can't understand this definition. Is there a simpler way this can be explained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

English is written and read left-to-right. If you use your mouse to select text, and you have dragged the mouse from the left to the right while making the selection, you have dragged the mouse "forward" along the line of text.

A user reading and writing a right-to-left language—such as Arabic—"forward" would be dragging the mouse from the right to the left to make the selection.