# for what is selectionDirection attribute in html?

Tags: html, attributes

I would like to know What action does it perform this attribute. I try select text from left to right and right to left and it work on both sides, so  What do I need this attribute?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431944/can-someone-better-explain-selectiondirection) help?

Comment: I read that post, but I can't understand the meaning of this attribute what does it do..

Comment: Can we say that the left-right or the right-left have any meaning in the javascript ?